# Calling C in RStudio causes crash

Tags: c, r, pointers, realloc

I am constantly facing a fatal error when calling a C function in R and I suspect it may be because of the way I have used "realloc" routine for variable n_k in the gCRSF_gibbs function. Can somebody tell me if the reallocation of memory to n_k is correct or not?

```
void gCRSF_gibbs(double *z, double **n_k, double *SampleDex,
             double *r, double *a, double *p,
             int *Ksize, int *WordNum) {

int i, j, k;
double mass;

double *prob_cumsum;
double cum_sum, probrnd;

prob_cumsum = (double *) calloc(Ksize[0],sizeof(double));

mass = r[0]*pow(p[0],-a[0]); 
for (i=0;i<WordNum[0];i++){
    j = (int) SampleDex[i] -1;
    k = (int) z[j] -1;
    if(z[j]>0){
        (*n_k)[k]--;
    }
    for (cum_sum=0, k=0; k<Ksize[0]; k++) {
        cum_sum += (*n_k)[k]-a[0];
        prob_cumsum[k] = cum_sum;
    }

    if ( ((double) rand() / RAND_MAX * (cum_sum + mass) < cum_sum)){
        probrnd = (double)rand()/(double)RAND_MAX*cum_sum;
        k = BinarySearch(probrnd, prob_cumsum, Ksize[0]);
    }
    else{
        for (k=0; k<Ksize[0]; k++){
            if ((int) (*n_k)[k]==0){
                break;
            }
        }
        if (k==Ksize[0]){
            Ksize[0]++;
            realloc(*n_k,sizeof(**n_k)*Ksize[0]);
            (*n_k)[Ksize[0]-1]=0;
            prob_cumsum =  realloc(prob_cumsum,sizeof(*prob_cumsum)*Ksize[0]); 
        }
    }
    z[j] = k+1;
    (*n_k)[k]++;
}
free(prob_cumsum);}
```

And this is how it is called in R:

```
gCRSF_gibbs <- function(z, n_k, sampleDex, r, a, p){
out <- .C("gCRSF_gibbs", z=as.double(z), n_k=as.double(n_k), 
          SampleDex=as.double(sampleDex), r=as.double(r), a=as.double(a),
          p=as.double(p), Ksize=as.integer(length(n_k)),
          WordNum=as.integer(length(sampleDex)))
out}
```

Comment: And how are we calling this function? (Include your R code.)

Comment: _I have used "realloc" routine"_: Don't. See Writing R Extensions.

Comment: And if you're open to using C++  (which better for R, really) then Rcpp has a bunch of Gibbs sampler examples _that work_.

Comment: Hi Dirk! Can you be more specific about not using realloc? Which part of writing R extensions are you referring to?

Answer (score -1):

You're using `realloc` wrong. It should be:

```
*n_k = realloc(*n_k,sizeof(**n_k)*Ksize[0]);
```

You always want to use `realloc` like `p = realloc(p, size)`. Otherwise, if the buffer gets moved by `realloc`, `*n_k` will be pointing to a freed pointer.

Comment: Actually this is wrong. If `realloc` fails it returns `NULL` and now you cannot free the memory and so leak. This has been covered many many times. http://stackoverflow.com/a/9071582/505088

Comment: Ok, you don't *always* want to use `p = realloc(p, size)`. But this guy is probably some masters student writing a program he'll run once and never again, he doesn't need the most robust solution. Besides, even if he detects he's out of memory, all he can do is print "oh no!" before exiting.

Comment: I don't agree. I don't see the point in doing it wrong. Why not get it right?

Comment: Furthermore, `*n_k` wasn't allocated by the C code's malloc. It's memory owned by R. It cannot be reallocated. So even when you fix the use of `realloc`, it will still be wrong because you cannot use `realloc` on this block of memory.