# Can i use dynamic memory allocation to reduce an int array's size and then reallocate memory?

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, realloc

I have created a program which counts how many times a `string` in a list has been found and prints that number on the screen and saves it in an `int *arr`. However, when there are two same `strings` , the `count` result is obviously printed & stored twice in the output/list. My question is this: Can i check if a word has been found twice and if so, then `free` that memory block and use `realloc()` to reallocate memory for the whole `int *arr` ? Here's my `sortedCount()` method which does what i stated above so far:

```
void sortedCount(int N) {
    int *wordCount;
    int i = 0;
    wordCount = malloc(N * sizeof(int));
    for(i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        wordCount[i] = count(N,wordList[i],1);
    }
    /* free mem */
    free(wordCount);
    return;
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but I am not able to match your description and code.

Comment: @SouravGhosh sorry english is not my strongest skill. Let me try again: forget about the example above and let's say that i have an array like this: `int *ptrArray;`. Now, let's say that it has a size of `malloc(N * sizeof(int));` but i now want it to be smaller by one int (removing one element) e.g: `malloc((N-1) * sizeof(int));` . Can i do that using `realloc()`?

Comment: @SteliosPapamichail short answer: yes. This may be helpful: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc

Comment: @woz ok thank you, and if i was to do `free(ptrArray[i])` and then use `realloc()` would that free up the memory for the `i`th element? I mean is there danger of mem leaks, should i be careful of something?

Comment: @SteliosPapamichail, regarding the memory leak possibility, I think this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9071566/is-it-safe-to-use-realloc) explains how you can use `realloc()` safely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say you have a dynamically allocated array of `words` words:

```
char  **word;
size_t  words;
```

If you want to know the number of unique words, and the number of times they repeat in the array, you can use a simplified version of a [disjoint-set data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure) and an array of counts.

The idea is that we have two arrays of `words` elements each:

```
size_t *rootword;
size_t *occurrences;
```

The `rootword` array contains the index of the first occurrence of that word, and `occurrences` array contains the number of occurrences for each first occurrence of a word.

For example, if `words = 5`, and `word = { "foo", "bar", "foo", "foo", "bar" }`, then `rootword = { 0, 1, 0, 0, 1 }` and `occurrences = { 3, 2, 0, 0, 0 }`.

To fill in the `rootword` and `occurrences` arrays, you first initialize the two arrays to "all words are unique and occur exactly once" state:

```
    for (i = 0; i < words; i++) {
        rootword[i] = i;
        occurrences[i] = 1;
    }
```

Next, you use a double loop. Outer loop loops over unique words, skipping the duplicates. We detect duplicates by setting their `occurrence` count to zero.  The inner loop is over the words we don't know if are unique or not, and pick off the duplicates of the currently unique word:

```
    for (i = 0; i < words; i++) {

        if (occurrences[i] < 1)
            continue;

        for (j = i + 1; j < words; j++)
            if (occurrences[j] == 1 && strcmp(word[i], word[j]) == 0) {
                /* word[j] is a duplicate of word[i]. */
                occurrences[i]++;
                rootword[j] = i;
                occurrences[j] = 0;
            }
    }
```

In the inner loop, we obviously ignore words that are already known to be duplicates (and `j` only iterates over words where `occurrences[j]` can be only `0` or `1`).  This also speeds up the inner loop for later root words, because we only compare candidate words, not those words we've already found a root word for.

Let's examine what happens in the loops with `word = { "foo", "bar", "foo", "foo", "bar" }` input.

```
 i ╷ j ╷ rootword  ╷ occurrences ╷ description
───┼───┼───────────┼─────────────┼──────────────────
   │   │ 0 1 2 3 4 │ 1 1 1 1 1   │ initial values
───┼───┼───────────┼─────────────┼──────────────────
 0 │ 1 │           │             │ "foo" != "bar".
 0 │ 2 │     0     │ 2   0       │ "foo" == "foo".
 0 │ 3 │       0   │ 3     0     │ "foo" == "foo".
 0 │ 4 │           │             │ "foo" != "bar".
───┼───┼───────────┼─────────────┼──────────────────
 1 │ 2 │           │             │ occurrences[2] == 0.
 1 │ 3 │           │             │ occurrences[3] == 0.
 1 │ 4 │         1 │   2     0   │ "bar" == "bar".
───┼───┼───────────┼─────────────┼──────────────────
 2 │   │           │             │ j loop skipped, occurrences[2] == 0.
───┼───┼───────────┼─────────────┼──────────────────
 3 │   │           │             │ j loop skipped, occurrences[3] == 0.
───┼───┼───────────┼─────────────┼──────────────────
 4 │   │           │             │ j loop skipped, occurrences[4] == 0.
───┼───┼───────────┼─────────────┼──────────────────
   │   │ 0 1 0 0 1 │ 3 2 0 0 0   │ final state after loops.
```

Comment: thank you so much for this answer i think this is what i want to recreate. One question before i give your answer another look, shouldn't the inner loop be `for(j = i+1; j < words; j++) {}` ?

Comment: @SteliosPapamichail: Good catch! Yes, indeed the inner loop should be `for (j = i + 1; j < words; j++) { ... }`. Now fixed. Thanks for noticing that!

Comment: awesome, i also have another question regarding the use of the final state of `rootword` and `occurences` for my program. Now in order for me to put those unique words in a separate array for e.g: sorting, would i have to loop over the elements of `rootword` and `occurences` and check 1) if i haven't seen the `rootword[i]` element before, add `word[rootword[i]]` to the list of unique words and 2) if `occurences[i] > 0` at the same time? (Let me know if i didn't state my question good enough so that i can try again)

Comment: @SteliosPapamichail: No, you'd just look at `occurrences[i]`. If it is zero, word `i` is a duplicate.

Comment: got it, thank you so so much, your answer was straight forward and easy to understand, thank you once again. Btw, can i ask you another question via chat about a problem that i encountered when recreating the program?

Comment: @SteliosPapamichail: I do not do chats, sorry.  You can ask me via email, though, if you like; the address is shown on my [home page](https://www.nominal-animal.net/).

Comment: no problem, just sent you an email :) . Thanks for everything!